# Unified Accounts

Tags: extrinsic, evm, frontier, moonbeam, session

We have followed the comets of `moonBeam` and implemented `Unified Accounts`. Now we're facing issues while adding `session keys` for `aura`, `grandpa` and `I'm online`.
we're using [this method](https://github.com/AsadAli-BB/storage-chain-poa/blob/b7e07cbb9e2d8917e8dd22be0b9eedb8f27a3264/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L55C1-L57) for `Aura and Grandpa` session keys generation. How we can attach a wallet address with these session keys?
When we try to generate session keys through polkaDot explorer by using `rotate-keys` method and then try to add these session keys so it create error [mentioned in image](https://ibb.co/zbVqrtH)

[image]

**There's conflict in between session keys generation. How we can fix this ?**